# Xcode 5 does not display assembly for arm64

Tags: ios, assembly, xcode5, arm64

Xcode 5 does not appear to build assembly output for 64-bit arm iOS Device.

I have created a simple iOS Empty project.

Then, in the Build Settings, set the VALID_ARCH to arm64, and set ARCH to Standard architectures (including 64-bit).

Finally, displaying main.m in the editor window, then requested Assembly output with menu Product->Perform Action->Assemble "main.m".

Instead of an assembly for main.m, the window displays "Unable to figure out how to generate assembly for main.m".

I have tried this with both Xcode 5.0 and 5.0.1.  Assembly output does work when VALID_ARCH is armv7 armv7s (the 32-bit code is correctly displayed.) Also, I have been able to cut the working arm7 assembly command line from the Log Navigator, change the -arch armv7 to -arch arm64, and paste into Terminal, with the correct 64-bit assembly output file, main.s, produced.

BTW, the Log Navigator shows several lines for 32-bit arm (including Compile main.m with the -S option), but for arm64, the Log Navigator shows only "Build succeeded"; this makes me think the xcodebuild rule is missing, or Xcode is not producing the xcodebuild command line.

So, has anyone else tried to display assembly output for arm64, and if so, has anyone found a way to accomplish the output within Xcode IDE?  Or, is it time for a radar?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Assistant Editor display and look at the "Disassembly" option. This gives me the output for ARMv8. There is an option to look at the Assembly as well.